# I’m good at remembering numbers. / I’m good at remembering figures

Tags: word-choice

For example, I'm an accountant on a job interview. Which sentence is more appropriate there? Could you explain it? For me, "figures" sounds more professional.

> I’m good at **remembering numbers**.

> I’m good at **remembering figures**.

Comment: Just 'good at figures' would be fine, although that would be a bit like a doctor saying 'I'm good with illnesses'. It's not remembering numbers (we have spreadsheets for that) that matters for an accountant, but understanding what they mean in context. I'm an accountant, and one of the boring parts of my job is people thinking it's just about "figures".

Comment: In the US at least, "figures" is pretty dated. I think my grandfather used to say it - he'd be 96 now. Younger people don't say it.

Comment: @cruthers - in the UK, 'figure' is still in use, either as a particular amount expressed as a number, especially a statistic, or just 'number'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Figures" is a pretty old-fashioned term to use , "numbers" is usually always better. Yes it can be more "professional", but in this case being an accountant, "figures" might be more *appropriate*. But it's up to you usually.

Comment: figures is not old-fashioned at all in business  reporting, etc.